# How to provide value from the same row to scala spark substring function?

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark

I've got following Dataframe with `fnamelname` column that I want to transform:

```
+---+---------------+---+----------+--------+
| id|     fnamelname|age|       job|ageLimit|
+---+---------------+---+----------+--------+
|  1|    xxxxx xxxxx| 28|   teacher|      18|
|  2|  xxxx xxxxxxxx| 30|programmer|       0|
|  3|    xxxxx xxxxx| 28|   teacher|      18|
|  8|xxxxxxx xxxxxxx| 12|programmer|       0|
|  9| xxxxx xxxxxxxx| 45|programmer|       0|
+---+---------------+---+----------+--------+
only showing top 5 rows

root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- fnamelname: string (nullable = true)
 |-- age: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- job: string (nullable = true)
 |-- ageLimit: integer (nullable = false)
```

I want to use `ageLimit` as a len value within `substring` function, but somehow `.cast("Int")` function doesn't apply to a value of that row.

```
val readyDF: Dataset[Row] = peopleWithJobsAndAgeLimitsDF.withColumn("fnamelname",
  substring(col("fnamelname"), 0, col("ageLimit").cast("Int")))
```

All I'm getting is:

```
 found   : org.apache.spark.sql.Column
 required: Int
        col("fnamelname"),0, col("ageLimit").cast("Int")))
```

How to provide a value of another column as a variable to function within `.withColumn()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`substring` function](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions$.html#substring(str:org.apache.spark.sql.Column,pos:Int,len:Int):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) takes an `Int` argument for the substring length. `col("ageLimit").cast("Int")` is not `Int` but another `Column` object holding the integer values of whatever was in the `ageLimit` column.

Instead, use the [`substr` method](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Column.html#substr(startPos:org.apache.spark.sql.Column,len:org.apache.spark.sql.Column):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) of `Column`. It has an overload that takes two `Column`s for the position and the substring length. To pass a literal `0` for the position column, use `lit(0)`:

```scala
val readyDF = peopleWithJobsAndAgeLimitsDF.withColumn("fnamelname",
  col("fnamelname").substr(lit(0), col("ageLimit")))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't do this directly using `substring` (or any other function with similar signature). You must use `expr`, so solution would be something like:

```
peopleWithJobsAndAgeLimitsDF
.withColumn(
  "fnamelname",
  expr("substring(fnamelname, 0, ageLimit)")
)
```